# Cassandra INSERT query Error

Tags: php, database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql

I'm getting an error with my Insert query in cassandra "ERROR: line 5:75 mismatched input '-02' expecting ')'  (log_sid)"

My Query is:

```
   INSERT INTO table_name(account_sid, datetime_uuid, log_add_name, log_detail, log_post_back, log_post_front, log_price, log_request_type, log_sid) VALUES ('YTe9e7d2f82f2d88db31cfcafd9f4a7a2d', 2016-02-12 11:45:37, 'Birthday gft','{"Postcard_message":"","Postcard_size":"1001","Postcard_data":""}', 'pdf file google storage path1', 'pdf file google storage path2', 0.8750,'postcard', 'psc_5823b1cb9445335d');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like for log_detail you are using map and passing values in quotes'' which is incorrect.

Use something like below:

```
INSERT INTO post_log(account_sid, datetime_uuid, log_add_name, log_detail, log_post_back,
      log_post_front, log_price, log_request_type, log_sid)
    VALUES ('YTe9e7d2f82f2d88db31cfcafd9f4a7a2d', '2016-02-12 11:45:37','Birthday gft',
      {"Postcard_message":"","Postcard_size":"1001","Postcard_data":""},
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/m360103069/directmail/postcard/psc_5823b1cb9445335d_back.pdf',
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/m360-103069/directmail/postcard/psc_5823b1cb9445335d_front.pdf',
      '0.8750','postcard', 'psc_5823b1cb9445335d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code may be help you

```
INSERT INTO post_log(account_sid, datetime_uuid, log_add_name, log_detail, log_post_back, log_post_front, log_price, log_request_type, log_sid)
   VALUES ('YTe9e7d2f82f2d88db31cfcafd9f4a7a2d', '2016-02-12 11:45:37','Birthday gft','{"Postcard_message":"","Postcard_size":"1001","Postcard_data":""}','https://storage.googleapis.com/m360103069/directmail/postcard/psc_5823b1cb9445335d_back.pdf', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/m360-103069/directmail/postcard/psc_5823b1cb9445335d_front.pdf','0.8750','postcard', 'psc_5823b1cb9445335d');
```

Comment: It give me this error when executed your query ERROR: Invalid STRING constant (2016-02-12 11:45:37) for 
"datetime_uuid" of type timeuuid

Comment: what you have use datetime_uuid datatype

Comment: datetime_uuid is name of column ,its type is "reversed<timeuuid>"